# Login impossible with Spotify iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, spotify

I can't login with ios sdk spotify.

I followed the Brian's tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO00YdJ3cE) and there is a difference with the current spotify tutorial :

In the video it talks about token exchange and show a spotify webpage. However on current spotify webpage the paragraph is missing.

Does this exchange token must be installed ?

I defined all elements in my spotify app account.
I also defined in the URL schemes : "spotify-action", "my-app-Name" but I can't sucess login.

Anyone help please ?

Comment: Hard to tell when you´re not adding any code, show this link if it can help you. This guy has the same problem as you have. https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/543

Answer (score 3):

There are two options: 
1) Implicit Grant Flow - grants users access tokens that will expire in 60 minutes - it is much simpler but has it's limits if you want to build a usable application. I will give you a simple example with spotify's updated sdk framework (you don't have to use safari)..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SPTAuthViewDelegate {
let kclientID = ""
let kcallbackURL = ""

@IBAction func loginSpotify(sender: AnyObject){
SPTAuth.defaultInstance().clientID = kclientID
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().redirectURL = NSURL(string: kcallbackURL)
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope]
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().sessionUserDefaultsKey = "SpotifySession"
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenSwapURL = NSURL(string: ktokenSwapURL) //you will not need this initially, unless you want to refresh tokens
    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().tokenRefreshURL = NSURL(string: ktokenRefreshServiceURL)//you will not need this unless you want to refresh tokens

    spotifyAuthViewController = SPTAuthViewController.authenticationViewController()
    spotifyAuthViewController.delegate = self
    spotifyAuthViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    spotifyAuthViewController.definesPresentationContext = true
    presentViewController(spotifyAuthViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }


func authenticationViewController(authenticationViewController: SPTAuthViewController!, didLoginWithSession session: SPTSession!) {
    print("Logged In")
}

func authenticationViewController(authenticationViewController: SPTAuthViewController!, didFailToLogin error: NSError!) {
    print("Failed to Log In")
    print(error)
    authenticationViewController.clearCookies(nil)
}

func authenticationViewControllerDidCancelLogin(authenticationViewController: SPTAuthViewController!) {
    print("User Canceled Log In")
    authenticationViewController.clearCookies(nil)
}
}
```

2) Authorization Code Flow - Spotify's authentication server sends an encrypted refresh token which you store, for example,

`SPTAuth.defaultInstance().sessionUserDefaultsKey = "SpotifySession"`. When that sessions expires you must trigger a function on your server... Hope this helps you get started